# How to run Capistrano task locally from remote server?

Tags: ruby, ssh, capistrano, resque, capistrano3

**Use case:**
Suppose I have a Capistrano task defined, for example `cap resque:start`.
It takes `:set` values such as amount of workers from my `deploy.rb`.
Suppose I want to start resque workers on server reboot.
I can copypaste them to some **post-reboot** script, but if I change `:set` amount of workers or other configs, I'll need to change **post-reboot** script as well.

Instead of that, we can execute `cap locally:resque:start` in our **post-reboot** script, which will automatically take current amount of workers we set in `deploy.rb`.

Comment: why on earth the downvote, this is an extremely useful feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. in **Gemfile**, add all Capistrano gems from `:development` to `:production`
2. create a task `cap locally:resque:start`:

   ```
   namespace :locally do
     namespace :resque do
       task :start do
         run_locally { Rake::Task["resque:start"].execute }
       end
     end
   end
   ```
3. add remote host to your `authorized_keys` on remote host (because Capistrano 3 requires stage set even if we are executing task locally. luckily ssh connection to localhost will be fast):

   1. `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
   2. `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
   3. `chmod og-wx ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
4. and now, on your remote production server, `cap production locally:resque:start`.